# How to find number of integers in a given range has even set bits

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, binary

I want to know how many numbers say x, in a given range lets say l and r, l < r, present where number of 1's in binary representation of x is even. Is there any efficient way to find that?

Comment: Is there any reason you are trying to do this algorithmically? `int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x)` is very fast and really I can't think of a range large enough where an algorithm would be that much of a speed difference.

Comment: @EliSadoff There is NO __builtin_popcount in c++. It's a built in function of GCC.

Comment: For example, on a 64 bit architecture, I looped through every single unsigned int and got the number of numbers with even bit totals with this as my `time` result `2.50s user 0.01s system 98% cpu 2.557 total`.

Comment: @ChenChen It exists in g++ as well.

Comment: Search the internet for "bit twiddling".

Comment: @EliSadoff I should say it's a function built in GNU compiler suite but not C++ itself.

Comment: I am stunned that g++ and gcc share functionality. Never saw that coming.

Comment: @user4581301 I know it's a shocker

Comment: @ChenChen I now understand what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a key fact:

- If *n* is a non-negative *even* number, then exactly half of the non-negative integers less than *n* have even parity and the other half have odd parity. ("Even parity" means that the number of bits in the binary representation is even.)

Suppose we need to count the number of integers in the range [*l*, *r*) with some property *P*, and we know how to solve this problem for any range where *l* is 0. ( "[*l*, *r*)" is a "half-open range": all integers *n* where *l*≤*n*<*r*. That makes the arithmetic easier.) Then we just need to subtract in order to solve the general problem where *l*≠0: COUNT[*l*,*r*) = COUNT[0,*r*) − COUNT[0,*l*).

The first fact doesn't quite tell us all we need to know, since it only works for even *n*. But if *n* is odd, *n-1* is even, and all we need to do is check the parity of *n-1* itself, which is the extra number not in the range [0,*n*-1).

Putting all that together, if we have the range [*l*, *r*), we compute the count as follows:

- COUNT(0,*l*) is *l*/2 if *l* is even, and (*l*-1)/2+PARITY(*l*) if *l* is odd
- COUNT(0,*r*) is *r*/2 if *r* is even, and (*r*-1)/2+PARITY(*r*) if *r* is odd
- COUNT(*l*,*r*) is COUNT(0,*r*) − COUNT(0,*l*)

That last computation requires at most two parity computations, regardless of how large the range is, as well as a couple of divisions and a subtraction.

If this were a mathematics site, I might feel compelled to prove the assertion in the key fact at the beginning, but since this is CS I will content myself with a proof outline. We first note that if *i* is even, then PARITY(*i*) and PARITY(*i*+1) are different (since the binary representations only differ in the last bit). Conversely, if *i* is odd, then PARITY(*i*) and PARITY(*i*-1) are different. Now, take all the integers in [0,*n*) and divide them into the set of integers with odd parity and the set with even parity, and consider the homomorphism

*f*(*i*)⇒*i*+1 if *i* is even; 

 *f*(*i*)⇒*i*−1 if *i* is odd;

The image of *f* over one of the two subsets of [0,*n*) is the other subset, since the parity of *f*(*i*) is different from the parity of *i*. So the two subsets are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your range falls in positive integer domain, I wrote the following C++ code

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath> 
using namespace std;

int find_even_bits_helper(int upper, int level, bool sign) {
    // find even-bit number starting from 0
    // level and sign just for printing purpose 
    for (int i = 0; i <= level; ++i) cout << ' ';
    cout << "[0," << upper << "] -> " << '\n';
    int answer;
    if (upper == -1) {
        answer = 0;
    }
    else if (upper == 0) {
        answer = 1;
    }
    else if ((upper & (upper + 1)) == 0) {
        answer = (upper + 1) / 2;
    }
    else {
        int threshold = pow(2, floor(log2(upper)));
        int base_part = find_even_bits_helper(threshold - 1, level + 1, sign);
        int extra_part = (upper - threshold + 1) \
                       - find_even_bits_helper(upper - threshold, level + 1, !sign);
        // Essentially remove the highest 1 bit, thus all odd-bit becomes even-bit 
        answer = base_part + extra_part;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= level; ++i) cout << ' ';
    if (sign) cout << "+";
    else cout << "-";
    cout << answer << '\n';
    return answer;
}

int find_even_bits(int lower, int upper) {
    return find_even_bits_helper(upper, 0, true) \
         - find_even_bits_helper(lower - 1, 0, false);
}

int main() {
    cout << "Result is: " << find_even_bits(7,34) << '\n';
}
```

Testing range [7, 34] outputs:

```
 [0,34] ->
  [0,31] ->
  +16
  [0,2] ->
   [0,1] ->
   -1
   [0,0] ->
   +1
  -1
 +18
 [0,6] ->
  [0,3] ->
  -2
  [0,2] ->
   [0,1] ->
   +1
   [0,0] ->
   -1
  +1
 -4
Result is: 14
```

It shows that [0, 34] has 18 even-bit integers and [0, 6] has 4 even-bit integers.

Therefore, the answer is `18 - 4 = 14`.